# JOINING a query from 2 tables - Multiple Results

Tags: mysql, sql-server, join

Could someone please tell explain to me how to properly process a query that collects information from 2 tables, i thought I had this figured out until I added more records. Please look at the image I have below:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iko0l.png)

(The last record should not have the name "Thomas Murray" in it)

Then there is the query I am processing:

```
"select a.*, b.forenames, b.surname FROM playerSkills a, playerdb b GROUP BY sheetNo"
```

What I was hoping to do is collect all from the playerSkills database (which it does) and only bring over the names from the second database (playerdb) that matched with the playerID but as I want to return more than one result so I don't know what to do as it returns the whole column and just pastes the one name into every field.

Though I am sure a JOIN is to be inserted here, I am not sure which or at all.

I am not experienced with SQL but trying to wrap my head around it. I have experimented with the JOIN clauses but didn't get far probably due to a syntax.

How can join the names to the playerID so they appear in the appropriate fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need columns to join on . . . and proper `join` syntax:

```
select ps.*, p.forenames, p.surname
FROM playerSkills ps JOIN
     playerdb p
     ON ps.playerId = p.playerId;
```

Notes:

- Your query does not require `GROUP BY`.
- Your query does require `JOIN` conditions.
- Kudos for using table aliases.  They should be abbreviations for the table name.
- You want to always use *explicit* `JOIN` syntax.  *No* commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: I see what you have done in the query to JOIN the two playerID columns to get the data. I ran the query and it displays the information correctly. Thank you for helping me with this and thank you for supplying notes on my query.